# Cloudflare Version 2 Challenge - Cloudscrapper

Tags: python, web-scraping, package, cloudflare

I've been using cloudscrapper for a little while now but recently I've been getting the below error. The site that I am trying to scrape from has DDOS protection from cloudflare. However, I was wondering if there is anything I could to get around this. Thanks.

I'm using the python package.

```
Detected a Cloudflare version 2 challenge, This feature is not available in the opensource (free) version.
```